# Everyday Inventory If inventory shows negative value select next stocktaking and subtract from it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
     Stocktaking Table 
 StoreID      Date    ProductCode      Qty
    1     2016-07-30    11             58
    1     2016-09-30    11             97
    2     2016-08-30    12             15
    2     2016-09-22    55             10
    3     2016-09-05    55             10


   Sale Table
  StoreID   Date    ProductCode Qty
    1      2016-08-30   11      40
    2     2016-08-30    12      3
    2     2016-08-30    55      4
    3     2016-08-30    55      6

Desired Output


   StoreID  Date    Productcode Qty
    1      2016-08-30   11      18
    2      2016-08-30   12      12
    2     2016-08-30    55      6
    3      2016-08-30   55      4
```

> parameter

```
 @ date1 and @date2 @storeid
```

I need to show everyday inventory; I can show `stocktakingQty -saleQty = Todayinventory`

> I got like this

```
 StoreID    Date    Productcode Qty
    1   2016-08-30     11       18
    2   2016-08-30     12       12
    2   2016-08-30     55       -4
    3   2016-08-30     55       -6
```

I can’t able to show negative value here .
Problem here was they forget to take stocktaking during `8th month` `store ID 3,2` but they sold that `product Code 55` on `2016-08-30`. next month they have stock taken that `product Code 55` during `9th month`.
I’m not sure how to do it !!bcoz  if its only negative qty value I need to select next month stock taken date or else I have select 8th stock taken date.

maybe somebody could help with it!!

```
Declare  
          @date1 date = '2015-06-01'
              ,@date2 date = '2015-06-30'
                ,@StoreNo Nvarchar(Max)=' AND S.StoreNo IN (61,68,450,451,430,917,918,919,921,923,925,930,935)'


--AS
BEGIN
             IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..#calender') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #calender
                IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Temp
                 IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##Inv1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Inv1
                 IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##Inv2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Inv2
                  IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..#Stock') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Stock
                  IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##StoreList') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##StoreList
                    IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##final') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##final
                     IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##product') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##product

     Declare @sql_store nvarchar(max)
            SET @sql_store = 
                            'SELECT StoreNo,StoreName INTO ##StoreList FROM Store S WHERE S.StoreNo IN  (61,68,450,451,430,917,918,919,921,923,925,930,935)' + @StoreNo
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_store


            Declare 

                 @date_s char(10) = cast(@date1 as varchar)
                ,@date_e char(10) = cast(@date2 as varchar)
                ,@date_index date


                    create Table #calender  (Date date)
                    SET @date_index = @date1

                    WHILE @date_index<=@date2
                    BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO #calender
                    SELECT @date_index

                    SET @date_index = dateadd(day,1,@date_index)

                    IF @date_index>@date2
                    Break
                    ELSE
                    Continue
                    END


       BEGIN
                SELECT 
                             ProductNo as ProductBarCode,Date

                        INTO ##product
                                    FROM Product,#calender

                    WHERE StartUseDate <= @date_s AND EndUseDate >=@date_e and IsInUsed = 1

        END

create table #inventory (StoreNo int ,Date date, ProductBarCode varchar(14),ProductQty int )



      BEGIn

                    Select 
                                       STD.StoreNo As StoreNo
                                       ,CheckDate as Date
                                       ,ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode
                                      , SUM( StocktakingQty)AS ProductQty
                            INTO ##Temp   
                                    From StockTakingDetail STD
                Inner Join
                             (Select     
                                        StoreNo
                                        ,CheckNo
                                        ,CheckDate 
                                     From StockTakingMain SM )StocktakingMain 
                                 On STD.CheckNo =StockTakingMain.CheckNo
                               where STD.StoreNo IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )
                           group By STD.StoreNo,STD.ProductBarCode,CheckDate




                SELECT A.StoreNo as StoreNo ,C.[date] as Date,A.ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode,A.ProductQty as ProductQty

                            INTO ##inv1
                                FROM  #calender C
                                OUTER APPLY 
                                (
                                    SELECT TOP 100 percent * FROM ##Temp I WHERE I.Date < C.DATE and StoreNo IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )   ORDER BY I.Date
                                ) A
                                OPTION (maxrecursion 0)



             INSERT INTO #inventory
                      Select  S.StoreNo,s.Date,s.ProductBarCode,ISNULL (sum(s.ProductQty),0) as ProductQty

                        From
                        (Select StoreNo,Date,ProductBarCode,ProductQty from ##inv1 where  Date between @date_s and @date_e and StoreNo IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )


                        Union all
        --Buy
                             Select
                                  BuyStore as StoreNo
                                     ,BuyDate as Date 
                                   ,ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode
                                     ,SUM(BuyQty)as Qty

                                            from BuyDetail BD
                        Inner Join 
                              ( Select 
                                  BuySerialNo
                                    ,BuyDate 
                                         from BuyMain BM) BuyMain ON BD.BuySerialNo = BuyMain.BuySerialNo
                            where  
                                   BuyDate Between @date_s and @date_e and BuyStore IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )
                            Group BY
                                   BuyDate,BuyStore,ProductBarCode,BuyDate   
                                                  )S
                        GROUP BY s.StoreNo,s.Date,s.ProductBarCode   

            END




       BEGIN 

            select
                 S.Date as Date,S.StoreNo As StoreNo,(S.ProductBarCode ) as ProductBarCode,sum(S.Qty) as ProductQty
        INTO #Stock
            from 
                --- sale
                (
                    select  
                                StoreNo As StoreNo,
                                PluCode as ProductBarCode,
                                cast (sum(BuyPoint/100)as int)*(-1) as Qty,
                                Date as Date
                    from POS_ItemTran p  
                    where 
                            Date between  @date_s and @date_e and p.StoreNo IN(select StoreNo from ##StoreList)
                    Group by 
                            PluCode,StoreNo,Date

                union all 

                 --Transfer IN
                        select   
                                 TD.TargetStoreNo as StoreNo
                                 ,TD.ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode
                                 ,SUM(TD.AcceptQty) as Qty
                                 ,AcceptDate as Date  
                                            from TransferDetail TD
                Inner join
                             (Select  TransferSerialNo
                             ,AcceptDate 
                                   from TransferMain )TM

                      ON TM.TransferserialNo = TD.TransferserialNo
                          where 
                                  AcceptDate between @date_s and @date_e and TargetStoreNo IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )
                               Group by 
                                     TargetStoreNo,TD.ProductBarcode,AcceptDate

                 union all

                 -- Transfer out
                             Select 
                                TD.TransferStoreNo as StoreNo
                                , TD.ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode
                                ,SUM(TD.TransferQty)*(-1) As Qty
                                ,TransferDate as Date 
                                           from TransferDetail TD 
                 Inner Join
                            (Select TransferSerialNo
                                      ,TransferDate 
                                             from TransferMain)TMO
                              On TMO.TransferSerialNo = TD.TransferSerialNo
                         where 
                                 TransferDate between @date_s and @date_e and TransferStoreNo IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )
                        Group by 
                                 TD.TransferStoreNo,TD.ProductBarCode,TransferDate

                 --Loss
                UNION ALL

                    SELECT
                            StoreNo
                            ,LossProductBarCode
                            ,SUM(LossQty)*(-1) as Qty,
                            LossDate as Date

                                FROM LossDetail LD
                INNER JOIN  
                    (SELECT 
                         StoreNo
                         ,LossSerialNo
                         ,LossDate  
                             FROM LossMain LM)LossMain ON LD.LossSerialNo = LossMain.LossSerialNo
                      where 
                           LossDate between @date_s and @date_e and StoreNo IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )
                    GROUP BY 
                           StoreNo,LossProductBarCode,LossDate

         Union All
                    --RCVBackDetail
                        Select 
                           RcvBackStoreNo as StoreNo
                           ,ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode
                           ,SUM(RcvBackQty) as Qty
                           ,RcvBackDate as Date
                        from RcvBackDetail RBD
                    Inner Join
                        (SELECT RcvBackSerialNo
                                ,RcvBackDate 
                                     FROM RcvBackMain)RcvBackMain
                        ON RcvBackMain.RcvBackSerialNo = RBD.RcvBackSerialNo 
                        Where 
                             RcvBackDate Between @date_s and @date_e and RcvBackStoreNo IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )
                        Group By 
                              RcvBackDate,RcvBackStoreNo,ProductBarCode


                )S
                        Group by S.StoreNo,S.ProductBarCode,S.Date

        END

        BEGIN

        Select 
              f.StoreNo,f.Date,f.ProductBarCode,SUM(f.ProductQty) as ProductQty
        INTO ##Inv2 
        From 
        (Select StoreNo,Date,ProductBarCode,ProductQty From #inventory i
   union all
         Select StoreNo,Date,ProductBarCode,ProductQty From #Stock st)f
         Group By f.Date,f.ProductBarCode,f.StoreNo
         End


    BEGIN 
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)  

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([StoreNo])   
                    FROM ##StoreList
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE  
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')   
        ,1,1,'')  

    SELECT @query =   
'SELECT * FROM  
(SELECT       
    [StoreNo],
      p.Date as Date
    ,p.ProductBarCode
    ,(ProductQty) as productQty
FROM ##inv2 f
Right Join ##product P ON p.ProductBarCode =f.ProductBarCode and p.Date =f.Date
where 
 p.ProductBarCode IN(2300028813032,2221400000393,2300011512096,2300021714060)
 )X  
PIVOT   
(  
    SUM(ProductQty)  
    for [StoreNo] in (' + @cols + ') 
) P' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query   
END
Drop Table #inventory
--Drop Table #calender
IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..#inventory') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #inventory
IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..#calender') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #calender
IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Temp
 IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##Inv1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Inv1
                 IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##Inv2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Inv2
                  IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..#Stock') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Stock
                  IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##StoreList') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##StoreList
                   IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##final') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##final
                    IF Object_ID(N'tempdb..##product') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##product

END
```

Comment: Please post what you tried so far.

Comment: @StackUser posted my code so for i tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT A.StoreNo as StoreNo ,C.[date] as Date,A.ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode,A.ProductQty as ProductQty
                                   INTO ##inv1

                                    FROM  #calender C
                                    OUTER APPLY 
                                    (
                                        SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 percent * FROM ##Temp I WHERE I.Date <= C.DATE and StoreNo IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )   ORDER BY I.Date
                                    ) A 
                                    --where A.productBarcode =2300007115072
                                    OPTION (maxrecursion 0)

                    SELECT B.StoreNo as StoreNo ,C.[date] as Date,B.ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode,B.ProductQty as ProductQty
                                INTO ##inv2     

                                    FROM  #calender C
                                    OUTER APPLY 
                                    (
                                        SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 percent * FROM ##Temp I WHERE I.Date >= C.DATE and StoreNo IN (select StoreNo from ##StoreList )   ORDER BY I.Date
                                    ) B 
                                    --where A.productBarcode =2300007115072
                                    OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
BEGIN 
                           Select 
                                        i.StoreNo
                                         ,i.Date
                                          ,i.ProductBarCode
                                            ,ISNULL(i.ProductQty - (Select SUM(Productqty) from #Stock st where st.Date<=i.Date and i.StoreNo =st.StoreNo and i.ProductBarCode= st.ProductBarCode),i.ProductQty ) as ProductQty
                            INTO ##final1
                                        From #inv1 i
                                        left join #Stock s 
                                             on s.storeno=i.storeno
                                                 and s.productbarcode=i.productbarcode
                                                 and s.date=i.date
                                                --where i.ProductBarCode IN(2221400000393)
                                                 Order By StoreNo,Date ,productBarcode
                              Select 
                                        i.StoreNo
                                         ,i.Date
                                          ,i.ProductBarCode
                                            ,ISNULL(i.Qty - (Select SUM(Productqty) from #Stock st where st.Date<=i.Date and i.StoreNo =st.StoreNo and i.ProductBarCode= st.ProductBarCode),i.Qty ) as ProductQty
                            INTO ##final2
                                        From #inv2 i
                                        left join #Stock s 
                                             on s.storeno=i.storeno
                                                 and s.productbarcode=i.productbarcode
                                                 and s.date=i.date
                                                --where i.ProductBarCode IN(2221400000393)
                                                 Order By StoreNo,Date ,productBarcode

         END



         BEGIN 

            Select f1.StoreNo as StoreNo,f1.Date as Date,f1.ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode,
                   case when f1.ProductQty <0 then f2.ProductQty else f1.ProductQty end as ProductQty 
            INTO  ##final3
             From  ##final1 f1
             Full  Outer Join ##final2 f2 
             ON f2.Date = f1.Date and f2.ProductBarCode = f1.ProductBarCode and f1.StoreNo = f2.StoreNo
       order By Date
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works out what is instock and on order at 30/08, works out the salesqty and then calculates the remaining stock in 2 stages. Note - the input data is not quite the same as yours - this is so that I would test a couple of scenarios,

```
declare @st table(StoreID int   ,  Dte date,    ProductCode int,      Qty int)
insert into @st values
(    1,     '2016-07-30',    11,             58),
(    1,     '2016-09-30',    11,             97),
(    2,     '2016-08-30',    12,             15),
(    2,     '2016-08-22',    55,             2),
(    2,     '2016-09-22',    55,             10),
(    3,     '2016-09-05',    55,             10)

declare @s table (StoreID  int,  Dte date,   ProductCode int, Qty int)
insert into @s values
 (   1,     '2016-08-30',   11,      40),
 (   2,     '2016-08-30',    12,      15),
 (   2,     '2016-08-30',    55,      4),
 (   3,     '2016-08-30',    55,      6)


drop table #temp
 ;with cte as
 (
 select t.storeid,t.stockstatusdate,t.productcode,sum(t.instock) instock ,sum(t.onorder) onorder
 from
 (
 select st.storeid
        , year(st.dte) * 12 + month(st.dte) yyyymm
        ,  2016 * 12 + 8 as stockstatusdate
        , st.productcode, 
        isnull(case when year(st.dte) * 12 + month(st.dte) <= 2016 * 12 + 8 then sum(st.qty)  end ,0)as instock,
        isnull(case when year(st.dte) * 12 + month(st.dte) > 2016 * 12 + 8 then sum(st.qty) end ,0)  as onorder
 from @st st
 group by st.storeid
        , year(st.dte) * 12 + month(st.dte)
        ,st.productcode
) t 
group by t.storeid,t.stockstatusdate,t.productcode
)
select  cte.storeid,cte.stockstatusdate,cte.productcode,cte.instock,cte.instock as instockcalc,cte.onorder, cte.onorder as onordercalc,
        t.saleqty,t.saleqtycalc
into #temp
from    cte
join    
(select s.storeid,year(s.dte) * 12 + month(s.dte) as salesdate,s.productcode ,sum(s.qty) as saleqty, sum(s.qty) as saleqtycalc
from    @s s 
group by s.storeid,year(s.dte) * 12 + month(s.dte),s.productcode
) t on t.storeid = cte.storeid and t.salesdate = cte.stockstatusdate and t.productcode = cte.productcode

--select * from #temp

update #temp
    set instockcalc = 
        case 
            when instockcalc >= saleqtycalc then instockcalc - saleqtycalc 
            else 0
        end,
        saleqtycalc = 
        case 
            when instockcalc >= saleqtycalc then 0 
            else saleqtycalc - instockcalc
        end
where   saleqtycalc > 0

update #temp
    set onordercalc = 
        case 
            when onordercalc >= saleqtycalc then onordercalc - saleqtycalc 
            else 0
        end,
        saleqtycalc = 
        case 
            when onordercalc >= saleqtycalc then 0 
            else saleqtycalc - onordercalc
        end
where   saleqtycalc > 0

--select * from #temp

select storeid,stockstatusdate,productcode,
        case 
            when instockcalc <> 0 then instockcalc
            else onordercalc
        end as qty
from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if below query would solve your problem completely, however case and datepart functions should be helpful.

Assuming we can consider stock quantity taken between 30th of previous month and 30th of this month as 30th of previous month, then below query would give the desired results

For ex: If stock taking done in sept 22 or 5th for that particular product of that store , then we can assume it should have actually taken place on 30th August.

```
SELECT st.StoreID, 
CASE 
WHEN st.date < (CAST(CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,st.date) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(mm, st.date) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '-30' AS DATE)) THEN
CAST(CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,st.date) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '-' + CAST((DATEPART(mm, st.date)-1) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '-30' AS DATE) 
WHEN st.date = (CAST(CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,st.date) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(mm, st.date) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '-30' AS DATE)) THEN st.date END AS [stockdate],
st.ProductCode,
s.date AS salesDate,
st.Qty - s.Qty AS InventoryQuantity 
FROM dbo.stocktaking st
LEFT JOIN dbo.SALE s
ON st.StoreID =s.StoreID
AND st.ProductCode = s.ProductCode
WHERE  CASE 
WHEN st.date < (CAST(CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,st.date) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '-' +  CAST(DATEPART(mm, st.date) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '-30' AS DATE)) THEN
CAST(CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,st.date) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '-' + CAST((DATEPART(mm, st.date)-1) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '-30' AS DATE) 
WHEN st.date = (CAST(CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,st.date) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(mm, st.date) AS VARCHAR(5)) + '-30' AS DATE)) THEN st.date END <= s.date
```